# Calling a function in the 'parent' when a Fancybox has closed

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm having troubles calling a function using the afterClose option in Fancybox. I've found numerous topics here about performing actions afterClose, but I haven't found an example of someone trying to call an 'external' function from there. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

I just have a function declared on my 'main' page (or parent):

```
function test(){
    alert('hello');
}
```

And my Fancybox options as follows:

```
window.project.fancyboxOptions = {      
    'autoSize':    true,
    'afterClose':  function(){
        window.test();
    },
    'openEffect':  'none'
};
```

These get passed into the Fancybox call directly. But I keep on getting 'undefined function' errors. What's the correct way of calling my 'global' function? (I've tried `test();`, `window.test()`, `window.parent.test();` etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: As long as `test()` really is declared in the window, this should work. Can you show the actual context of the declaration of the `test()` method?

Comment: It is declared in the head of the page you get back to when closing the Fancybox. Is that enough context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I declare the function as follows now:

```
window.project.test = function(){
    alert('hello');
};");
```

And call it with `window.project.test();`.

That does the job.